# Spring is committing transactions when I stop my application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot(1.5.8) application and I'm using @Transactional annotation in its Repository methods. 
Those methods are working fine when they finish and when there's an Exception.
But when I use Eclipse's stop button, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> at terminal or System.exit() to exit my application it commits current transaction instead of rollback it.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Throwable.class, propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )
public ArrayList<Item> saveItemBatch(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    ArrayList<Item> rejectedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        if(saveItem(item)==null) {
            rejectedItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    return rejectedItems;
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor=Throwable.class, propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )
public ArrayList<Item> saveItemBatchException(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    ArrayList<Item> rejectedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        if(saveItem(item)==null) {
            rejectedItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    if(items.size()>0) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return rejectedItems;
}
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Throwable.class, propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )
public ArrayList<Item> saveItemBatchExit(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    ArrayList<Item> rejectedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        if(saveItem(item)==null) {
            rejectedItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
    return rejectedItems;
}
private boolean saveITem(Item item) {

    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = ...;/*Get jdbcCall*/

    HashMap<String, Object> callParams = ...;/*get parameters map*/

    Map<String, Object> result = jdbcCall.execute(callParams);
    String errorCode = (String) result.get("ERROR_CODE");
    return (errorCode==null);
}
```

Each method **saveItemBatch*** has a loop inside, where they call an Oracle's stored procedure.

When I call **saveItemBatch** or **saveItemBatchException** it works as expected, on the first it commits and it rollbacks on the second one. 
But if I call **saveItemBatchExit** or I try to stop my application using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or Eclipse's stop button while it's calling **saveItemBatch** or **saveItemBatchException**, it commits its current transaction.

I'm using:
auto-commit = false
ojdbc6.jar

Comment: Killing an application means all bets are off. It is entirely possible that spring will simply stop instead of ending cleanly, or it might actually wait for the method to finish. Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using? Oracle is one of the few JDBC drivers that (used to?*) commit transactions on connection close (where other drivers rollback). That may be a factor here. *) it might have changed in recent versions, not entirely sure.

Comment: Either you don't have transactions (in which case I'm not sure why saveItemBatchException works, if you were using a library like Hibernate I would have said because of flush, but here I'm not sure), your database is not ACID (or you are using it in the wrong isolation level when reading the data after your tests) or you are reading the result of your tests in the wrong way, or maybe all of those.